# ng-repeat and select/optgroup not as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with using ng-repeat and select.

Here is my code, first of all

```
        <select>
            <optgoup ng-repeat="(key, value) in Widget.ids" label="{{ value.label }}">
                <option ng-repeat="id in Widget.ids[key].ids">{{ id }}</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

My data looks something like this

```
        [ 
        { label: "My Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ] },
        { label: "My Other Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ] }
        ]
```

However, this returns a completely empty `<select>`. 
What's frustrating, is if I change my HTML to look like this:

```
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in Widget.ids">{{ value.label }}
                <div ng-repeat="id in Widget.ids[key].ids">{{ id }}</div>
            </div>
```

Then it lists..

```
My label
one id
another id
My Other Label
one id
another id
```

In fact if I remove the `<select>` tag and leave the `optgroup` etc tags then it will actually generate the correct DOM elements.

Also, I can't use simply use ng-model as I will be reserving that for a different model. (Widget.my.path.widget_id)

What's going on here then?

Comment: I have found a solution issue by reformatting my data and using "ng-options", but I am still intrigued as to why the code in this question does not work!

Comment: Right, using something like "item.value as item.name group by item.groupName for item in vm.items" is the way to go. Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 3):

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIqV0EYyDWvHPLvPTWPC?p=preview) should work:

```
<select>
    <optgroup ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
      <option ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```