# ng-options with a complex multidimentional array of an objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

> My object in controller.js

```
$scope.militaryObject = [
            {
                label: "U.S. Air Force",
                options: [
                    {"name": "Active Duty", "value": "AF - Active Duty (AD)"},
                    {"name": "Selective Reserve", "value": "AF - Selective Reserve (SR)"},
                    {"name": "Spouse", "value": "AF - Spouse of AD or SR"},
                    {"name": "Veteran", "value": "AF - Veteran"},
                    {"name": "Civilian", "value": "AF - Civilian"},
                    {"name": "Air National Guard", "value": "AF - Air National Guard"}
                ]
            },{
                label: "U.S. Army",
                options: [
                    {"name": "Active Duty", "value": "AR - Active Duty (AD)"},
                    {"name": "Selective Reserve", "value": "AR - Selective Reserve (SR)"},
                    {"name": "Spouse", "value": "AR - Spouse of AD or SR"},
                    {"name": "Veteran", "value": "AR - Veteran"},
                    {"name": "Civilian", "value": "AR - Civilian"},
                    {"name": "Army National Guard", "value": "Army - Air National Guard"}
                ]
            },{
                label: "U.S. Coast Guard",
                options: [
                    {"name": "Active Duty", "value": "CG - Active Duty (AD)"},
                    {"name": "Selective Reserve", "value": "CG - Selective Reserve (SR)"},
                    {"name": "Spouse", "value": "CG - Spouse of AD or SR"},
                    {"name": "Veteran", "value": "CG - Veteran"},
                    {"name": "Civilian", "value": "CG - Civilian"}
                ]
            },{
                label: "U.S. Marine Corps",
                options: [
                    {"name": "Active Duty", "value": "MC - Active Duty (AD)", "selected" : "false"},
                    {"name": "Selective Reserve", "value": "MC - Selective Reserve (SR)"},
                    {"name": "Spouse", "value": "MC - Spouse of AD or SR"},
                    {"name": "Veteran", "value": "MC - Veteran"},
                    {"name": "Civilian", "value": "MC - Civilian"}
                ]
            },{
                label: "U.S. Navy",
                options: [
                    {"name": "Active Duty", "value": "NV - Active Duty (AD)"},
                    {"name": "Selective Reserve", "value": "NV - Selective Reserve (SR)"},
                    {"name": "Spouse", "value": "NV - Spouse of AD or SR"},
                    {"name": "Veteran", "value": "NV - Veteran"},
                    {"name": "Civilian", "value": "NV - Civilian"}
                ]
            },{
                label: "U.S. Department of Defense",
                options: [
                    {"name": "DoD Civilian", "value": "DoD - Civilian"}
                ]
            }
        ];
```

> I am trying to render this object into select using ng-option, here is
>   my code in .html file

```
<select ng-model="military" ng-options="value.options[key].name group by value.label for (key,value) in militaryObject"></select>
```

> This not working for me, its giving me this

```
<select ng-model="military" ng-options="value.options[key].name group by value.label for (key,value) in militaryObject" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
    <optgroup label="U.S. Air Force">
        <option label="Active Duty" value="object:9">Active Duty</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="U.S. Army">
        <option label="Selective Reserve" value="object:10">Selective Reserve</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="U.S. Coast Guard">
        <option label="Spouse" value="object:11">Spouse</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="U.S. Marine Corps">
        <option label="Veteran" value="object:12">Veteran</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="U.S. Navy">
        <option label="Civilian" value="object:13">Civilian</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="U.S. Department of Defense">
        <option label="undefined" value="object:14"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Its not rendering all the objects in options array. Please tell me what i am doing wrong
Please help!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using 'group by' (I dont know that function) but it seems to me it groups your objects so only one per group is rendered

Comment: Do you know an alternative way of doing this? I just want to render the true HTML against this object.

Comment: But then it would be a nested dropdown or something: You have groups with elements. You could loop through the groups and add the elements to a new list

Comment: Every label should have its own dropdown

Comment: No thats not an option... I think i have done using nested ng-repeat... just testing finally...

Comment: Ah, I see, you just need to nest ngRepeat. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007950/ng-repeat-and-select-optgroup-not-as-expected

Comment: yes.. but i am setting an empty option at the start.

Comment: then just ad an empty option to your object

Comment: flatten the array (simple task) and let angular build it for you as per the `ng-options` docs

Answer (score 0):

> This is how we can render the template against this complex object,
>   its basically by using nested ng-repeat

```
<select id="military" name="military" ng-model="military" ng-change="militaryChange()" style="color: #000;">
    <optgroup label="{{value.label}}" ng-repeat="(key,value) in militaryObject">
        <option value="{{v.value}}" ng-repeat="v in value.options">{{v.name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```